# Spring custom validation messages not used

Tags: spring, validation

I am using a `CustomDateEditor` to parse date-time values submitted as form values, and set up a `ValidationMessages.properties` properties file to provide the message text for validation failures. But Spring is still displaying the default ugly `IllegalArgumentException` message instead of the message text I've provided. What have I done wrong?

Comment: I am answering my own question, [as is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314862/spring-validations-default-messages : in that question the user did not use the normal name for the messages properties file (`ValidationMessages.properties`), so in that case it is clearer that you must tell Spring which properties file to use.

Answer (score 0):

Although `ValidationMessages.properties` is the normal location for validation messages, Spring does not load the messages from there by default. You must explicitly tell Spring to load those message, using a `ResourceBundleMessageSource` object. That is, with a bean definition like this:

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
       <list>
          <value>ValidationMessages</value>
       </list>
    </property>
 </bean>
```