# how to create a properties file for error messages thrown ny @Valid annotation in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have this class, where the field "nome" can't be empty

```
public class Utente {       
    ......

    @NotEmpty 
    @Size(min=2, max=30)
    private String nome;
    .......    
}
```

After the user fills and sends the form I call this method

```
    @RequestMapping("/formSent")
    public String formSentMethod(Model model, @Valid Utente utente, BindingResult result){
    .....
}
```

I print the error in the Eclipse's console with this plain code, put inside the formSentMethod method.

```
    @RequestMapping("/formSent")
    public String formSentMethod(Model model, @Valid Utente utente, BindingResult result){
    .....
    for(ObjectError errore : result.getAllErrors()){            
        System.out.println(errore.getDefaultMessage());         
    }
    .....
}
```

So far, I get the default error message "may not be empty", when the user doesn't fill the field "nome".

I tried to customize that message by using a properties file called messages.properties, that I put under WEB-INF/classes, as you can see in this pic [image]

Inside messages.properties I wrote

```
   NotEmpty.utente.nome = Il nome è obbligatorio
```

In my XXX-servlet.xml I "call" the properties file this way

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">   

            <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean> 

<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Since it didn't work I even tried editing the basename value this way

```
<property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/Classes/messages" />
```

but it didn't work as well.

I keep on getting the default error message and not my customized message "Il nome è obbligatorio". Probably what I wrote in my properties file is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you check your .war whether the messages.properties exists there?

Comment: Could you show the view/html part that shows the error?

Comment: @dieend I edited my post. So far i print the error message on the Eclipse's console.

Comment: I mean check whether the message.properties file exists in the war file. No need to change the value of messageSource. Looks like it can't load the messages.properties file. TGry to @Autowire the messageSource in your controller and check whether it contains the key/value pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

message.properties doesn't reference the class and field, but form name and the field. For example in this html:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="utente" action="customer/signup">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="nome" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="nome" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer Age :</td>
            <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="age" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

`NotNull.utente.nome` will be correct, because the form `utente` contains field `nome`. The important thing is, **it's not based on the class but the path in html**.

To access the internationalization from controller, you need `MessageSource` bean, and use the bean to get the internationalization.

Here is example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751603/how-to-get-error-text-in-controller-from-bindingresult) to access internationalization message in controller:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="ValidationMessages"/>
</bean>
```

Inject your `MessageSource` instance inside your Controller

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

And to get your message, do as follows

```
for (Object object : bindingResult.getAllErrors()) {
    if(object instanceof FieldError) {
        FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) object;

        /**
          * Use null as second parameter if you do not use i18n (internationalization)
          */

        String message = messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that message's should be placed inside `classes` but one level up, according to your configuration.

You could also make a absolute path like:

> /WEB-INF/classes/messages

or one level up

> /WEB-INF/messages

Also, remember that with this configuration, you're not setting default encoding, which may lead to some problems, I suggest set property `defaultEncoding` to `UTF-8`